# Não consigo pegar o nome do dominio com php

Tags: php, apache

Estou enfrentando um problema que é para pegar o nome do domínio do meu site. tentei o código:

```
define('PROTOCOL', 'http://');

define('DOMAIN', (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : ''));

define('SUB_FOLDER', str_replace('public', '', dirname((isset($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) ? $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] : ''))));

define('BASE_URL', PROTOCOL . DOMAIN . ((substr(SUB_FOLDER, -1, 1) == '/') ? substr(SUB_FOLDER, 0, strlen(SUB_FOLDER)-1) : SUB_FOLDER));
```

o problema e que o HTTP_HOST me retorna o ip do servidor e não o dominio: **web.meusite.com.br**

Obs: meu site está em servidores cluster. ele tem um total de 10 servidores 5 no brasil e 5 nos estados unidos.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` para resgatar o domínio.

Seu código:

```
define('DOMAIN', (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] : ''));
```